# iOS 14 Datepicker issue with preferredDatePickerStyle set to compact

Tags: xcode, datepicker, crash, uidatepicker, ios14

My application in crashing when the user taps on the compact style Datepicker on iOS 14 when in the month of February only and Beirut Timezone.

**Steps to reproduce error:**

1. Open a new Xcode project targetting iOS 14 at least
2. Place a datepicker in the storyboard (By default, the style is Automatic and the mode is Date and Time)
3. Run on iOS 14 simulator or device
4. Make sure the date is in the month of february and your timezone is set to Beirut
5. Tap on the datepicker

**Expected behavior:** A dialog should open showing the full datepicker menu

**Actual Behavior:** App crashing

**Error:**

```
Exception   NSException *   "Invalid calculation: number of calculated days is not dividable by the number of days in a week."
```

Is anyone having a similar issue?

Comment: I am also having a similar issue. Crashlytics is reporting this crash in our live app, on iOS 14.4.0 (18D52). Will have to move back to wheels style date picker for now, it seems.

Comment: I also see this issue on my iOS app. It seems that this is some bug in iOS / UIDatePicker itself. Have you found any workaround?

Comment: I also see this. Date picker doesn't even have to be opened. Only Beirut, not Damascus or Amman which are also EET (GMT+2).
Crash is on this statement: picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
*** Assertion failure in -[_UIDatePickerCalendarDaySet daysForMonth:includingOverlapDays:], _UIDatePickerCalendarDaySet.m:132
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid calculation: number of calculated days is not dividable by the number of days in a week.'

Comment: You can recreate by setting the device's time zone to Beirut, while leaving the current Region to United States (or any region other than Lebanon).

Force current Region to Lebanon in Edit Scheme -> Options -> App Region and it doesn't crash. But setting the picker's locale to en_LB (Lebanon) doesn't help.

There must be something specific about the mismatch of time zone and region for Lebanon but I haven't found it. A (poor) workaround might be to identify the mismatch and switch the picker.preferredDatePickerStyle to .wheel in that case only.

Comment: I changed the Time Zone to Cairo as a workaround. In terms of development I had to opt out from new iOS date picker style and use wheels.